# Inside TextChanged I want to get control which contains text box

Tags: c#, textbox

I have several text boxes which use the same TextChanged method. How inside this TextChanged method can I get the object which contains the text box which fired event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextBox` that fired the event is contained in the `sender` parameter of the event handler. You just need to write:

```
TextBox senderTB = (TextBox)sender;
Control container = senderTB.Parent;

//If container is custom
//You could cast or use as here depending on having a different parent is valid
MyControl customContainer = (MyControl)senderTB.Parent;
```

The container of a control is in the `Parent` property ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need TextBox, I need control which contains this TextBox (panel, for example)

Comment: @lit17 Updated to show use of the `Parent` property

Comment: @lit17 Applied the second edit. You can just comment if you want :) No need to suggest edits with "thanks" in them and such.